# Busybox running PHP script with httpd on debian linux

Tags: javascript, php, html, httpd.conf, busybox

I've got busybox running and the service shows on my browser when I type the IP of my raspberry PI. I'm trying to run the php script Configuration page, but it won't execute just displays the code on the webpage. I have installed php 7.3 and php cgi 7.3. What am I missing, or doing wrong? appreciate any help! Thank you.

I could only think that I missed mounting something correctly.
It's inside my /media/velchro. It's an external drive for my raspberry PI.
Maybe wrong version PHP, doesn't support the version for busybox. I have tried researching, and pretty much stumped at this point.

To execute the code and show the configuration page of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your web server is not correctly configured to handle PHP scripts. You need to tell the server that .php files are special and that they should be handled by an external service, otherwise it will treat them as regular text files and display its contents instead (like you are describing).

The configuration is specific to each web server and I don't know which one you are using (although the most common ones are Apache and NGINX).

I don't know about Busybox, but after a quick search it seems that it ships with a basic [web server](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/http.httpd#cgi_scripts) that doesn't have a lot of features but seems capable to do what you want, [after some configuration](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=7405.0).

Good luck.